# How to validate console command prompt inputs

Tags: laravel, validation, command, laravel-5.4

Following console command I'm prompting for input. I would like to validate the user input. How can I do that?

I have check the [this plugin](https://github.com/cerbero90/command-validator). But it looks like validating arguments & options. Not the interactive inputs.

**CreateClient.php**

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class CreateClient extends Command {
    ...

    public function handle() {
        $name   = $this->ask('Enter name ');
        $email  = $this->ask('Enter email ');
        $date   = $this->ask('Enter date [Eg: 2016-01-01 00:00:00] ');

        // Validate user input
        $this->info('Validating user inputs');

       // How to validate email & date format ?
    }
}
```

**Update**

Yes I'm aware of `Validator`, but the concern is the validation stops the user journey. User have restart from the beginning. Is it possible to attach a validation to each question, so the validation will be immediate and prompt to enter again.

Below is something I notice when I doesn't enter any value, I'm wondering how can I provide more validation rule.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

Since class `\Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle` supports passing validation callback as third parameter, I wrote a below function and calling it.

```
/**
 * Prompt the user for input.
 *
 * @param  string $question
 * @param  string $default
 * @param  callable|null $validator
 * @return string
 */
public function askWithValidation($question, $default = null, $validator = null)
{
    return $this->output->ask($question, $default, $validator);
}
```

General validation function

```
use Validator;

/**
 * Validates the user input
 *
 * @param string $attribute
 * @param string $validation
 * @param string $value
 * @throws Exception
 * @return string
 */
protected function validateInput(string $attribute, string $validation, $value)
{
    if (! is_array($value) && ! is_bool($value) && 0 === strlen($value)) {
        throw new \Exception('A value is required.');
    }

    $validator = Validator::make([
        $attribute => $value
    ], [
        $attribute => $validation
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        throw new \Exception($validator->errors()->first($attribute));
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Call :

```
$contactEmail = $this->askWithValidation('Enter contact email ', null, function ($value) {
    return $this->validateInput('contactEmail', 'email', $value);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Below is another way you can do it using Laravel's Validator.

My custom method `validate_cmd` takes 2 parameters:

1. A `Command` method (ask, secret, choice...) as an anonymous function
2. An array of the rules

If validation fails the `Command` method will be called again.

Of course you would want to place this in a Trait.

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Validator;

class CreateClient extends Command {

    public function handle() {

        $name = $this->validate_cmd(function() {
            return $this->ask('Enter name');
        }, ['name','required']);

        $email = $this->validate_cmd(function() {
            return $this->ask('Enter email');
        }, ['email','required|email']);

        $date = $this->validate_cmd(function() {
            return $this->ask('Enter date [Eg: 2016-01-01 00:00:00]');
        }, ['date','required']);

    }

    /**
     * Validate an input.
     *
     * @param  mixed   $method
     * @param  array   $rules
     * @return string
     */
    public function validate_cmd($method, $rules)
    {
        $value = $method();
        $validate = $this->validateInput($rules, $value);

        if ($validate !== true) {
            $this->warn($validate);
            $value = $this->validate_cmd($method, $rules);
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function validateInput($rules, $value)
    {

        $validator = Validator::make([$rules[0] => $value], [ $rules[0] => $rules[1] ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $error = $validator->errors();
            return $error->first($rules[0]);
        }else{
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I posted my solution, please take a look

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) and [`Carbon`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
public function handle() {
    $name   = $this->ask('Enter name ');
    $email  = $this->ask('Enter email ');
    $date   = $this->ask('Enter date [Eg: 2016-01-01 00:00:00] ');

    // Validate user input
    $this->info('Validating user inputs');

    // How to validate email & date format ?
    $email_status = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

    if (!$email_status) {
        // Invalid EMAIL
    }

    if (\Carbon::createFromFormat('YOUR DATE FORMAT', $date) === false) {
        // Invalid date
    }

}
```

Another method would be as said by @btl using [`Validator`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators)

```
public function handle() {
    $name   = $this->ask('Enter name ');
    $email  = $this->ask('Enter email ');
    $date   = $this->ask('Enter date [Eg: 2016-01-01 00:00:00] ');

    // Validate user input
    $this->info('Validating user inputs');

    $data = array(
        'email' => $email,
        'date'  => $date
    );

    $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'date'  => 'required|date',
    );

    $validator = \Validator::make($data, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->messages();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was expecting more like when user enter a invalid email it returns error immediately. The concern with this is user have to enter all the inputs then realise the validation fails.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly modified version of `Erevald`'s since I also required a similar function.

```
public function validate_console($method, $rules)
{
    $value = $method();
    $validate = $this->validateInput($rules, $value);

    if ($validate !== true) {
        $messages = collect($validate->messages())->flatten()->all();
        foreach ($messages as $failure) {
            $this->warn($failure);
        }
        $value = $this->validate_console($method, $rules);
    }
    return $value;
}

public function validateInput($rules, $value)
{
    $validator = Validator::make([key($rules) => $value], $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $validator->errors();
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$client_name = $this->validate_console(function() {
        return $this->ask('What should I call you? (Client Name)');
    }, ['client_name' => 'email|min:4']);
```

Output:

```
The client name must be a valid email address.
The client name must be at least 4 characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Validator instance and setup your corresponding rules.

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Contracts/Validation/Validator.html

Specifically, see the make() method.

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Contracts/Validation/Factory.html

```
public function handle()
{
    $name = $this->ask('Enter name ');
    $validator = \Validator::make(['name' => $name], ['name' => 'required|string']);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $message = $validator->messages();
    }
    $email = $this->ask('Enter email ');
    $validator = \Validator::make(['email' => $email], ['email' => 'required|email']);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $message = $validator->messages();
    }
    $date = $this->ask('Enter date [Eg: 2016-01-01 00:00:00] ');
    $validator = \Validator::make(['date' => $date], ['date' => 'required|datetime']);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $message = $validator->messages();
    }

    // so something with $message
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was expecting more like when user enter a invalid email it returns error immediately. The concern with this is user have to enter all the inputs then realise the validation fails. Sorry for not making the question not clear

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from validating between each input. ask -> validate -> ask -> validate.... and so on.

Comment: Yes good point, but then the journey stops there. It won't prompt the question again. I updated the question